# SOAP Envelope of BaseClass

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have two classes

```
public class Person
{
    public String ForeName {get;set;}
    //...
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public String LastName{get;set;}
    //...
}
```

If I now return the `Customer` via a SOAP Service, it will only show the LastName in the SOAP Envelope Sample in the list of operations.

**Webmethod:**

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "getCustomer")]
public Customer GetCustomer()
{
    return new Customer();
}
```

**Response example:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getCustomerResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getCustomerResult>
        <LastName>string</LastName>
      </getCustomerResult>
    </getCustomerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

*Note:
The Code works fine, the WSDL is correct. I am only interested in the correct SOAP Envelope.*

**Question:**
How can I mark the `Customer` so that it will also display the properties of `Person`  ?

I am using C# ASP.Net in the Framework is 3.5

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262246/asmx-web-service-not-serializing-abstract-base-class

Comment: No, the comment underneath the answer states my problem again : "it seems to generate the correct code, **it just doesn't display in the sample.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bug in the product as microsoft states it:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520200/inherited-properties-do-not-appear-in-soap-sample-on-asmx-file

I found an answer in another question which seems to have the same problem.
[Inherited properties do not appear in soap sample on asmx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875642/inherited-properties-do-not-appear-in-soap-sample-on-asmx-file)